# What does this character from PUBG mean in Chinese? (Character identified: 魂)

Tags: character-identification, games

[image: What does this character mean?]

I saw it in PUBG game. Thanks!

Comment: It means 'soul, spirit' in Chinese, but Japanese like to use it on there clothes.it could also mean 'faith, vitality' in Japanese.

Answer (score 2):

It is "魂", and there are several meanings of it.
Probably the most common one is soul, but usually the meaning is some kind of phantom things related with one's soul or one's characters.

Answer (score 2):

in Chinese  it means soul  and it also means spirit

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to specifically mean the human "soul", in some religious, other worldly sense, you say 灵 魂.

Because 灵 means spirit also, and to just say 魂 means spirit lacks accuracy.

Between the two, 灵 has a much wider usage as it could also mean something non-other Worldly, or non-spiritual, such as 机灵, (smart), 灵活, (agile), whereas 魂 is confined to the non-human spiritual other Worldly realm.

As in English, you say "competitive spirit", you don't say "competitive soul" So do not use 魂 if you wish to mean the "spirit" in this sense.